# .split() function giving IndexError: list index out of range with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Code:

```
url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=CN&language=english&currency=23&item_nameid=1321474'
source = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, timeout=10)
source.encoding = 'utf-8'
if(source.ok != True):
    print(f'\nError: {source.status_code}\n')
    return 0
soup = str(BS(source.text, 'lxml'))
print(soup)
print(type(soup))
steam = []
steam.append(int(soup.split(""""sell_order_summary":"<span class='\"market_commodity_orders_header_promote\"'>""")[1].split(' for sale')[0])) # Sell Quantity
print(steam)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ultralight\REQUESTS_MODULE.py", line 188, in <module>
    print(request_buff_steam_item('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Desert%20Eagle%20%7C%20Blaze%20%28Factory%20New%29'))
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\ultralight\REQUESTS_MODULE.py", line 182, in request_buff_steam_item
    steam.append(int(soup.split(""""sell_order_summary":"<span class='\"market_commodity_orders_header_promote\"'>""")[1].split(' for sale')[0])) # Sell Quantity
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Soup:

```
<html><body><p>{"success":1,"sell_order_table":"</p><table class='\"market_commodity_orders_table\"'><tr><th align='\"right\"'>Price</th><th align='\"right\"'>Quantity</th></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 2,225.62</td><td align='\"right\"'>1</td></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 2,249.90</td><td align='\"right\"'>1</td></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 2,258.02</td><td align='\"right\"'>1</td></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 2,274.40</td><td align='\"right\"'>1</td></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 2,299.79</td><td align='\"right\"'>2</td></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 2,300 or more</td><td align='\"right\"'>35","sell_order_summary":"<span class='\"market_commodity_orders_header_promote\"'>41 for sale starting at <span class='\"market_commodity_orders_header_promote\"'>\u00a5 2,225.62","buy_order_table":"<table class='\"market_commodity_orders_table\"'><tr><th align='\"right\"'>Price</th><th align='\"right\"'>Quantity</th></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 2,105.45</td><td align='\"right\"'>1</td></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 1,949.09</td><td align='\"right\"'>1</td></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 1,948.99</td><td align='\"right\"'>2</td></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 1,948.30</td><td align='\"right\"'>1</td></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 1,946.05</td><td align='\"right\"'>1</td></tr><tr><td align='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 1,938 or less</td><td align='\"right\"'>2510","buy_order_summary":"<span class='\"market_commodity_orders_header_promote\"'>2516 requests to buy at <span class='\"market_commodity_orders_header_promote\"'>\u00a5 2,105.45 or lower","highest_buy_order":"210545","lowest_sell_order":"222562","buy_order_graph":[[2105.45,1,"1 buy orders at \u00a5 2,105.45 or higher"],[1949.09,2,"2 buy orders at \u00a5 1,949.09 or higher"],[1948.99,4,"4 buy orders at \u00a5 1,948.99 or higher"],[1948.3,5,"5 buy orders at \u00a5 1,948.30 or higher"],[1946.05,6,"6 buy orders at \u00a5 1,946.05 or higher"],[1938,8,"8 buy orders at \u00a5 1,938 or higher"],[1930,9,"9 buy orders at \u00a5 1,930 or higher"],[1897.65,10,"10 buy orders at \u00a5 1,897.65 or higher"],[1885.66,15,"15 buy orders at \u00a5 1,885.66 or higher"],[1870.29,16,"16 buy orders at \u00a5 1,870.29 or higher"],[1856.45,21,"21 buy orders at \u00a5 1,856.45 or higher"],[1826,22,"22 buy orders at \u00a5 1,826 or higher"],[1806.07,23,"23 buy orders at \u00a5 1,806.07 or higher"],[1800,25,"25 buy orders at \u00a5 1,800 or higher"],[1796.16,26,"26 buy orders at \u00a5 1,796.16 or higher"],[1769.68,27,"27 buy orders at \u00a5 1,769.68 or higher"],[1766,28,"28 buy orders at \u00a5 1,766 or higher"],[1763.37,29,"29 buy orders at \u00a5 1,763.37 or higher"],[1754.06,30,"30 buy orders at \u00a5 1,754.06 or higher"],[1750.46,31,"31 buy orders at \u00a5 1,750.46 or higher"],[1740,32,"32 buy orders at \u00a5 1,740 or higher"],[1734.78,33,"33 buy orders at \u00a5 1,734.78 or higher"],[1730.41,34,"34 buy orders at \u00a5 1,730.41 or higher"],[1728.1,35,"35 buy orders at \u00a5 1,728.10 or higher"],[1721.1,36,"36 buy orders at \u00a5 1,721.10 or higher"],[1719.55,37,"37 buy orders at \u00a5 1,719.55 or higher"],[1715.66,38,"38 buy orders at \u00a5 1,715.66 or higher"],[1712,39,"39 buy orders at \u00a5 1,712 or higher"],[1710.81,44,"44 buy orders at \u00a5 1,710.81 or higher"],[1708,45,"45 buy orders at \u00a5 1,708 or higher"],[1705,46,"46 buy orders at \u00a5 1,705 or higher"],[1701.08,47,"47 buy orders at \u00a5 1,701.08 or higher"],[1700.99,52,"52 buy orders at \u00a5 1,700.99 or higher"],[1700.13,54,"54 buy orders at \u00a5 1,700.13 or higher"],[1696.45,59,"59 buy orders at \u00a5 1,696.45 or higher"],[1693.09,60,"60 buy orders at \u00a5 1,693.09 or higher"],[1691.85,61,"61 buy orders at \u00a5 1,691.85 or higher"],[1671.38,62,"62 buy orders at \u00a5 1,671.38 or higher"],[1649.56,63,"63 buy orders at \u00a5 1,649.56 or higher"],[1635.34,64,"64 buy orders at \u00a5 1,635.34 or higher"],[1610,69,"69 buy orders at \u00a5 1,610 or higher"],[1600,73,"73 buy orders at \u00a5 1,600 or higher"],[1599.99,76,"76 buy orders at \u00a5 1,599.99 or higher"],[1595,78,"78 buy orders at \u00a5 1,595 or higher"],[1588,79,"79 buy orders at \u00a5 1,588 or higher"],[1587,80,"80 buy orders at \u00a5 1,587 or higher"],[1585.63,81,"81 buy orders at \u00a5 1,585.63 or higher"],[1579.99,82,"82 buy orders at \u00a5 1,579.99 or higher"],[1578.51,84,"84 buy orders at \u00a5 1,578.51 or higher"],[1577.41,85,"85 buy orders at \u00a5 1,577.41 or higher"],[1571.48,87,"87 buy orders at \u00a5 1,571.48 or higher"],[1532.16,88,"88 buy orders at \u00a5 1,532.16 or higher"],[1528.78,89,"89 buy orders at \u00a5 1,528.78 or higher"],[1508.12,90,"90 buy orders at \u00a5 1,508.12 or higher"],[1500,92,"92 buy orders at \u00a5 1,500 or higher"],[1499.99,94,"94 buy orders at \u00a5 1,499.99 or higher"],[1493.13,97,"97 buy orders at \u00a5 1,493.13 or higher"],[1489.31,99,"99 buy orders at \u00a5 1,489.31 or higher"],[1470.99,100,"100 buy orders at \u00a5 1,470.99 or higher"],[1457.65,101,"101 buy orders at \u00a5 1,457.65 or higher"],[1437.56,102,"102 buy orders at \u00a5 1,437.56 or higher"],[1436.3,103,"103 buy orders at \u00a5 1,436.30 or higher"],[1428.5,104,"104 buy orders at \u00a5 1,428.50 or higher"],[1427.97,106,"106 buy orders at \u00a5 1,427.97 or higher"],[1426.19,107,"107 buy orders at \u00a5 1,426.19 or higher"],[1422.09,109,"109 buy orders at \u00a5 1,422.09 or higher"],[1399.98,110,"110 buy orders at \u00a5 1,399.98 or higher"],[1395.35,111,"111 buy orders at \u00a5 1,395.35 or higher"],[1393.22,112,"112 buy orders at \u00a5 1,393.22 or higher"],[1386.59,113,"113 buy orders at \u00a5 1,386.59 or higher"],[1364.26,114,"114 buy orders at \u00a5 1,364.26 or higher"],[1359.34,115,"115 buy orders at \u00a5 1,359.34 or higher"],[1356.86,116,"116 buy orders at \u00a5 1,356.86 or higher"],[1350.94,117,"117 buy orders at \u00a5 1,350.94 or higher"],[1350.21,119,"119 buy orders at \u00a5 1,350.21 or higher"],[1336.8,121,"121 buy orders at \u00a5 1,336.80 or higher"],[1333.2,122,"122 buy orders at \u00a5 1,333.20 or higher"],[1319.39,123,"123 buy orders at \u00a5 1,319.39 or higher"],[1283.47,124,"124 buy orders at \u00a5 1,283.47 or higher"],[1250,126,"126 buy orders at \u00a5 1,250 or higher"],[1244.41,129,"129 buy orders at \u00a5 1,244.41 or higher"],[1229.44,130,"130 buy orders at \u00a5 1,229.44 or higher"],[1224.59,132,"132 buy orders at \u00a5 1,224.59 or higher"],[1221.5,133,"133 buy orders at \u00a5 1,221.50 or higher"],[1208.76,134,"134 buy orders at \u00a5 1,208.76 or higher"],[1149.88,136,"136 buy orders at \u00a5 1,149.88 or higher"],[1146.1,137,"137 buy orders at \u00a5 1,146.10 or higher"],[1141.96,139,"139 buy orders at \u00a5 1,141.96 or higher"],[1140.38,140,"140 buy orders at \u00a5 1,140.38 or higher"],[1118.1,142,"142 buy orders at \u00a5 1,118.10 or higher"],[1109.24,144,"144 buy orders at \u00a5 1,109.24 or higher"],[1084.71,145,"145 buy orders at \u00a5 1,084.71 or higher"],[1080.86,146,"146 buy orders at \u00a5 1,080.86 or higher"],[1080.38,147,"147 buy orders at \u00a5 1,080.38 or higher"],[1059.39,149,"149 buy orders at \u00a5 1,059.39 or higher"],[1046.1,150,"150 buy orders at \u00a5 1,046.10 or higher"],[1043,151,"151 buy orders at \u00a5 1,043 or higher"],[995.5,153,"153 buy orders at \u00a5 995.50 or higher"],[976.2,154,"154 buy orders at \u00a5 976.20 or higher"],[955.16,156,"156 buy orders at \u00a5 955.16 or higher"],[924.37,158,"158 buy orders at \u00a5 924.37 or higher"]],"sell_order_graph":[[2225.62,1,"1 sell orders at \u00a5 2,225.62 or lower"],[2249.9,2,"2 sell orders at \u00a5 2,249.90 or lower"],[2258.02,3,"3 sell orders at \u00a5 2,258.02 or lower"],[2274.4,4,"4 sell orders at \u00a5 2,274.40 or lower"],[2299.79,6,"6 sell orders at \u00a5 2,299.79 or lower"],[2300,7,"7 sell orders at \u00a5 2,300 or lower"],[2366.15,8,"8 sell orders at \u00a5 2,366.15 or lower"],[2415.3,9,"9 sell orders at \u00a5 2,415.30 or lower"],[2453.09,10,"10 sell orders at \u00a5 2,453.09 or lower"],[2500.95,11,"11 sell orders at \u00a5 2,500.95 or lower"],[2542.34,12,"12 sell orders at \u00a5 2,542.34 or lower"],[2616.55,13,"13 sell orders at \u00a5 2,616.55 or lower"],[2634.71,14,"14 sell orders at \u00a5 2,634.71 or lower"],[2644.65,15,"15 sell orders at \u00a5 2,644.65 or lower"],[2668.65,16,"16 sell orders at \u00a5 2,668.65 or lower"],[2737.03,17,"17 sell orders at \u00a5 2,737.03 or lower"],[2788.12,18,"18 sell orders at \u00a5 2,788.12 or lower"],[2829.77,19,"19 sell orders at \u00a5 2,829.77 or lower"],[2986.32,20,"20 sell orders at \u00a5 2,986.32 or lower"],[3189.03,21,"21 sell orders at \u00a5 3,189.03 or lower"],[3217.31,22,"22 sell orders at \u00a5 3,217.31 or lower"],[3270.69,23,"23 sell orders at \u00a5 3,270.69 or lower"],[3649.33,24,"24 sell orders at \u00a5 3,649.33 or lower"],[3832.89,25,"25 sell orders at \u00a5 3,832.89 or lower"],[3860.38,26,"26 sell orders at \u00a5 3,860.38 or lower"],[4025,27,"27 sell orders at \u00a5 4,025 or lower"],[4088.37,28,"28 sell orders at \u00a5 4,088.37 or lower"]],"graph_max_y":200,"graph_min_x":924.37,"graph_max_x":4088.37,"price_prefix":"\u00a5","price_suffix":""}</span></span></td></tr></table></span></span></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

For some reason when I try to reproduce the error without using soup and just setting soup = 'string', it returns the correct number `43`

Comment: Try running a `print(len(soup.split(""""sell_order_summary":"<span class='\"market_commodity_orders_header_promote\"'>""")[1].split(' for sale')))` To see if adding the [0] is what is causing this error.

Comment: also if you have any suggestions to make my code better that would be good

Comment: @LewisMenelaws same error

Comment: Your error might be coming from the `soup.split("....")[1]`. Can you try `print(len(soup.split('...')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was the backslash. The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character. The backslash appears in the original string but in your string it doesn't, it escapes the quotes. This should work.

```
steam.append(int(soup.split("""sell_order_summary":"<span class='\\"market_commodity_orders_header_promote\\"'>""")[1].split(' for sale')[0])) # Sell Quantity
```

Now the backslash is included in split string, because it is escaped with another backslash.

And this way of getting the information isn't really the nicest way. I would do something like this.

```
import json

json_obj = json.loads(source.text)
soup = BS(json_obj['sell_order_summary'], 'lxml')
steam = []
steam.append(int(soup.find('span').text))
```

Store the data in JSON format (because you are already scraping it as JSON) and then use BeautifulSoup like you should for searching tags and not just to make one big string from everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bs4.find()` to find certain tags from ids, classes, etc. Then you could try parsing the results in text. I'm not sure why you're having the issue with `soup.split()` but if you need to use it then I could look more into it.

Comment: but you still need to split() to get the numbers from `lign='\"right\"' class='\"\"'>\u00a5 2,249.90</td><td align='\"righ` right?